# Deploying Report(.rdl) and DataSet and Data Source to SharePoint 2013 Integrated mode

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I am searching for blog of MSFT article which speaks about publishing/deploying SSRS reports to DEV- QA - Acceptance - PROD SharePoint 2013 in Integrated mode.

Can someone advice if creating a feature/solution and packaging them for deployment is easy way or if there is another way to deploy this reports in the development lifecycle? with every environment(DEV, QA, UAT, PRod) the link within datasource changes which also needs to be dynamic, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Within the project properties in SQL Server Data Tools/BIDS, you can define your various environments and enter the appropriate urls for data sources, reports, and server that environment in the [deployment properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155802.aspx). Once these are set up, you can choose the correct configuration for the appropriate environment.  Then when you click deploy, it will go to the correct location for that environment. Do not be fooled by the Configuration drop-down box on the properties page.  You actually have to click the button to switch between configurations.

So change it here: 
[image]

Not here: [image]

For the data sources, make sure you are using shared data sources and that you set Overwrite data source in your project properties to false. Then update the data source to be appropriate to the environment and deploy it once in each environment. You won't have to do this in the future since it will now be out there. This means your SSRS data source must have the same name in each environment.  If you change it in the future, you need to update it and redeploy in each SharePoint environment. Here's a [blog post](http://aaron.hursman.com/2006/12/reporting-services-best-practices.html) describing this approach.

Comment: Thanks for showing me one of the way of doing it via BIDS. This way will work if Developer has access to Production URL's which may not be the case in real development life cycle. Please correct if wrongly stated.